# How to compare two consective numbers of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to compare two consecutive numbers of an array and print the largest one in every iteration. I have written below code but its giving unexpected responses. Can somebody please check and help me understand the mistake.

PS: I just started learning java.

```java
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String [] args){

       int[] list = {6,0,4,2,9};
       int current;
        for(int j=0; j<list.length-1; j++){
            if(list[j]>list[j+1]){
                current = j;
            }else{
                current = j+1;
            }
        System.out.print(current + " ");
        }
    }
}

Expected response: 6 4 4 9
Actual response: 0 2 2 4
```

Comment: You're adding 1 to ```j``` . ```j```  is an *index*. So - why? (at *current = j+1;*)

Comment: `unexpected responses` what response is unexpected?

Comment: The code currently prints the indices and not the actual  numbers which doesn't match your problem description.  Possible change is simply: `System.out.print(list[current]+" ");`

Answer (score -1):

Ok so your code is just returning `j` which here is used as the number in youy `for` loop.

In your `if` you're using `j` as an index to get the value in `list` matching that index; but in the rest of your `for` loop you're setting `current` to the value of `j` and not the value of `list` at the index `j`.

What you'll want to print is the value of `list[j]` and not `j`.

In fact, if you look closely `[0 2 2 4]` are the indexes of `[6 4 4 9]`